# Stretching and centering nested 2d flexbox element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
.outer {
    border: 2px solid red;
    display: flex;
}

.inner {
    border: 2px solid cyan;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    align-self: center;
}

.innest {
    border: 2px solid orange;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="innest">a</div>
    <div class="innest">b</div>
     <div class="innest">c</div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="innest">d</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've been trying to both stretch and center the 'd' element of the above code example for a while now, but haven't been able to come up with a solution. I have been able to either stretch it vertically, or center it vertically, but not both at the same time. How can I do that?

EDIT: I would like the element with the cyan border to extend the height of its parent (red), while its inner element (orange border) also extends the height of its parent (cyan). All while the 'd' content is being vertically centered.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you, but add .outer div {width:100%;} and tell me if you meant that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you're looking for

```css
.outer {
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
}

.inner {
  border: 2px solid cyan;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-self: center;
}

.second_inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: auto;
}

.second_inner .innest {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.innest {
  border: 2px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="innest">a</div>
    <div class="innest">b</div>
    <div class="innest">c</div>
  </div>
  <div class="second_inner">
    <div class="innest">d</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain why it doesn't work if second_inner uses flex-direction column?

Comment: when you do that you're just reverse the direction so it won't work